# In book class, how to create "top of page headers" that differ slightly from those I get if I do just nothing. My effort to do this is commented out

Tags: header-footer

```
\documentclass[english,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage{fancyhdr,fancyref} %
\usepackage{xcolor} %
\usepackage{colortbl} %
\usepackage[skins,theorems,most]{tcolorbox} %
\usepackage{xcolor} %
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,left=12.5mm,right=12.5mm,top=18mm,bottom=8mm,showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} %
\usepackage{libertine} %
\usepackage{hyperref}

% \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\fontsize{12.0}{14}\selectfont{\chaptername\hspace{2.8pt}\thechapter\hspace{8pt}-\hspace{8pt}#1}}{}} % 42

% \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\fontsize{12.0}{14}\selectfont{Section\hspace{3.6pt}\thesection\hspace{8pt}-\hspace{8pt}#1}}{}} % 32

% \fancypagestyle{mainstyle}{
% \fancyhead{} %
% \fancyfoot{} %
% \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark} %
% \fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} %
% \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\fontsize{11.15}{14}\selectfont{-\hspace{2pt}{\thepage}\hspace{2pt}-}} }

\begin{document}

\chapter{The undeveloped world}

Large areas of land where population density is low.

\section[the Amazon river basin]{The Amazon river basin}

\clearpage

\section[the African river Congo]{The African river Congo}

\clearpage

\chapter{The developed world}

The population density is high.

\section[Europe - from UK in north to Spain in south]{Europe - from UK in north to Spain in south}

\clearpage

\section[North America and Canada]{North America and Canada}

\clearpage

\section[the Philippenes]{Japan and the Philippenes}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: After all the years you should know, how to use markdown for block code. If not, please read the help.

Comment: I found my question very difficult to pose in the usual direct way.  I was hoping that someone  would uncomment my commented-out lines, and update them so as to duplicate - possibly with slight variations - the result you get by "doing nothing".  Then I would have the framework within which I (and others) could experiment with further detail.  It is the sequence of instructions and the detail, like: pagestyle{} or \fancypagestyle{} that confuses the end-user.  Give us a full working solution, please,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to define a specific page style, just issue `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Also, formatting istructions should be in the specifications for the header or footer, not in the instructions for the marks.

I changed hyphens into en-dashes: the hyphen is not the right choice, in my opinion (too thick and too short).

Don't forget to follow the advice of `fancyhdr` about `\headheight`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,fancyref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[skins,theorems,most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=170mm,
  paperheight=240mm,
  bindingoffset=12.5mm,
  left=12.5mm,
  right=12.5mm,
  top=18mm,
  bottom=8mm,
  headheight=14pt,% as requested by fancyhdr
%  showframe,
%  showcrop
]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\chaptername\hspace{2.8pt}\thechapter\hspace{8pt}--\hspace{8pt}#1}{}%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{Section\hspace{3.6pt}\thesection\hspace{8pt}--\hspace{8pt}#1}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\fontsize{12.0}{14}\selectfont\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\fontsize{11.15}{14}\selectfont{--\hspace{2pt}{\thepage}\hspace{2pt}--}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The undeveloped world}

Large areas of land where population density is low.

\section{The Amazon river basin}

\clearpage

\section{The African river Congo}

\clearpage

\chapter{The developed world}

The population density is high.

\section{Europe - from UK in north to Spain in south}

\clearpage

\section{North America and Canada}

\clearpage

\section{Japan and the Philippines}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I take it that each time \chapter  and \section are called, your defined page styles are automatically invoked.  Other headings like Comment and Bibliography can still have their own syles - that need to be defined and called?

Comment: Only chapters issue `\thispagestyle{plain}`. You can define other styles, if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can define new headings via [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)'s `\fancypagestyle` (as you did), but that won't impact their use unless you specify it, or change from the default. To do so, specify the new page style to be in use shortly after defining it:

```
%...
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%...
\fancypagestyle{mainstyle}{%
  % <your mainstyle page style definitions
}
%...
\pagestyle{mainstyle}% mainstyle page style in effect from here
%...
```

Of course, note that `\chapter`s have their own page style only for the first page, issued typically via `\thispagestyle{plain}`. If you want to override this behaviour, you can define a new style to replace `plain`, or redefine the `plain` page style.

---

Based on your specific example, this is what the input should look like (I removed a number of unnecessary packages from your example):

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,left=12.5mm,right=12.5mm,top=18mm,bottom=8mm,showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop}
\usepackage{libertine}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth
    {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\chaptername\hspace{2.8pt}\thechapter\hspace{8pt}-\hspace{8pt}#1}%
    {}%
} % 42

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright
  {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont Section\hspace{3.6pt}\thesection\hspace{8pt}-\hspace{8pt}#1}%
  {}%
} % 32

% Define mainstyle page style
\fancypagestyle{mainstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}%
  \fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}%
  \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\fontsize{11.15}{14}\selectfont -\hspace{2pt}{\thepage}\hspace{2pt}-}%
}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}% Based on the size of the header content

% Set mainstyle as the current page style
\pagestyle{mainstyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The undeveloped world}

Large areas of land where population density is low.

\section[the Amazon river basin]{The Amazon river basin}

\clearpage

\section[the African river Congo]{The African river Congo}

\clearpage

\chapter{The developed world}

The population density is high.

\section[Europe - from UK in north to Spain in south]{Europe - from UK in north to Spain in south}

\clearpage

\section[North America and Canada]{North America and Canada}

\clearpage

\section[the Philippenes]{Japan and the Philippenes}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Warner - thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  However, I cannot see how to accept your answer

Comment: @keith77777: Just below the voting buttons, at the top-left of every answer, you should see a shaded check mark. Clicking it accepts the answer. See [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)